# Remove horizontal grid lines only on wxgrid

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, wxwidgets

On the wxwidgets docs, I only found the EnableGridLines, which is set to false, removes both the horizontal and vertical lines, what I wish, is to remove only the horizontal lines on the grid. Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you either have all the lines or none of them. Feel free to try cross-posting on the wxPython mailing list to make doubly sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike. Unfortunately wx.grid.Grid.Get[Col|Row]GridLinePen() isn't hooked to the wxPython level, so you can't override those functions in your code. I had been hopeful that returning None would result in the line not being drawn.